# Getting the exact value of the Maclaurin series for $\sinh$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I am new to Maclaurin series and I am trying to find the exact value for $\sinh(x)$.
Let say I have the highest power of $5$ and value of $x$ is $2$.

How do I start??

Sorry I am really new to this.

Comment: The Maclaurin series for $\sinh x$ is $x+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+\frac{x^7}{7!}+\cdots$. You can get it from the definition of MacLaurin series, or by using the fact $\sinh x=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$ and what you know about the series for $e^t$. If $x=2$, the approximation obtained by truncating at the $x^5$ term is not great.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want the partial sum $\sum_{n=0}^5 2^n f^{(n)}(0)/n!$ where $f(x)=\sinh x$. The even derivatives at $0$ are $\sinh 0=0$ and the odd ones are $\cosh 0=1$, so you have $2^1/1!+2^3/3!+2^5/5!$, which is $2+8/6+32/120=18/5=3.6$.